# Node.js response headers are not set

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express, header

I'm trying to set Nodejs headers to the returned packet, but when logging the response it's always empty.

Here is my middleware in node.js server. It's supposed to add "From" header to the response, but it doesn't appear in the client logging the response.

---

EDIT:

In addition to changing res.set() to res.setHeaders() I had to access them at the client side using response.headers() instead of response.headers

---

```
app.use(function(reg, res, next){
        var checkAdmin = false;
        var bearerToken;
        var bearerHeader = reg.headers.authorization;
        if(admin.indexOf(reg.url) > -1){
                console.log("varmistetaan onko admin");
                checkAdmin = true;
                checkYourPrivilege(checkAdmin, bearerHeader, res, reg, next);
        } else if(public.indexOf(reg.url) < 0){
                console.log("varmistetaan onko suojattu");
                checkYourPrivilege(checkAdmin, bearerHeader, res, reg, next);
        } else {
                bearerToken = decodeToken(bearerHeader);
                if(bearerToken !== false){
                        decoded = verifyToken(bearerToken);
                        if(decoded !== false){
                                if (checkIfExpired(decoded.expires)){
                                        res.setHeader('From','test@test.com');
                                        next();
                                }else{
                                        res.set('From','test@test.com');
                                        next();
                                }
                        }else{
                                res.set('From','test@test.com');
                                next();
                        }
                }else{
                        res.set('From','test@test.com');
                        next();
                }
        }
});
```

Here is my angularjs interceptor, which is logging the response at the moment:

```
.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$window', '$localStorage', function($q, $window, $localStorage){
        return {
                'request': function (config){
                        config.headers = config.headers || {};
                        if ($localStorage.accessToken) {
                                config.headers.Authorization = 'bearer ' + $localStorage.accessToken;
                        }
                        return config;
                },
                'response' : function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        return response
                },
                'responseError': function(responseError){
                        responseError = JSON.parse(responseError.data);
                        if(responseError.tokenstatus === "expired"){
                                delete $localStorage.accessToken
                                window.location = "/";
                        }
                        if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                                window.location = "/";
                        }
                        window.location = "/";
                        return $q.reject(response);
                }
        };
}])
```

This is what the response looks like:

```
{…}
config: {…}
cache: Object { put: put(), get: get(), remove: remove(), … }
headers: Object { Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", Authorization: "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwcml2aWxlZ2VzIjp7ImFkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJhc3Vubm90IjpmYWxzZSwib3Bpbm5vdCI6ZmFsc2V9LCJvcHRpZXRvbWVtYmVyIjpmYWxzZSwiYXN1bm5vdG1lbWJlciI6ZmFsc2UsImV4cGlyZXMiOjE1MTYwNDA3MjksImlhdCI6MTUxNjAwNDcyOX0.hU8yT3G58ZtkJbBo-SUwLmcSMSX_8cHYxnX0GdmfJVM" }
jsonpCallbackParam: "callback"
method: "GET"
paramSerializer: function Ef/this.$get/<()
transformRequest: Array [ Df/this.defaults.transformRequest<() ]
transformResponse: Array []
url: "koti.html"
__proto__: Object { … }
data: "<h1>Tähän tulee kotisivun sisältö</h1>\n"
headers: wd/<() #Response headers should be here?
length: 1
name: ""
__proto__: function ()
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object { … }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.setHeader()`and `res.writeHead()` are a native method of Node.js and `res.set()` is a method from Express framework.

Documentation: [res.setHeader()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value),  [res.set()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) [res.writeHead](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

These three methods do exactly the same thing, set the headers HTTP response. The only difference is `res.setHeader()` and `res.writeHead()` allows you only to set a singular header and `res.set()` will allow you to set multiple headers. So use the one fit with your needs.

you can try any one of these:
`res.setHeader('From','test@test.com')` or
`res.writeHead(200,{'Form':'test@test.com'})`

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I tried using res.setHeader and logged the res -object at the server side. It does show the from -header at the serverside, but when doing console.log(response.headers) at the client it only shows an object named "function wd/<()" with absolutely no headers at all. EDIT: Seems like I need to read the headers using response.headers() instead of accessing an object named response.headers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @nyoatype Anytime!

Answer (score 0):

Try with res.setHeader in all places (not res.set)

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the original question indicated the use of AngularJS, and while the responses for that are probably helpful, they DO NOT seem to apply to later versions of Angular (i.e. version 2+).

I was using NodeJS/express middlewares to host a secure form of json-server, and I was trying to dump the contents of the `headers` collection to the console to see that they all came across correctly.  This is where I was going wrong, and here's why:

The `headers` property of the response object is not a method, but an object, and the headers are processed in a lazy-loaded manner.  This means that dumping the contents to the console yielded an entirely empty collection, making me believe I had a bug.  In order to access the full collection, you first need to call `rsp.headers.init()`.

Now, if you do not need to see the full collection, feel free to make calls for the specific values you need, through calls such as `rsp.headers.get("_returnCode")`.  When you make such calls, the `init()` method is called for you prior to attempting to return the first value, and all should work fine.

Hope this helps!